# Is there a library out there to analyze VB.Net code complexity from my C# code?

Tags: vb.net, code-metrics

Given VB.Net code in a string, is there a library (or a command line tool) out there that could calculate Cyclomatic Complextiy and LOC? 
This has to be done within my C# code.

Thanks.

Comment: What tool did you use for your C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Refactor!, which does supply some extensibility and also supplys the mesurements (And an extesibility point)

Besides that, there is also NDepend, which allows you to query your code for such infos:
http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx

Comment: Oh wow the Code Query Language stuff looks really cool. Thanks for pointing that out. So does Refactor also have similar features, which can be accessed from my code?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible. But they have some extensibility points.